# Symfony 2 loading xml validation of bundle

Tags: php, symfony

How do I import the validation.xml into the project ?

Because now it just seems to get ignored and not loaded.

I've tried:

```
- { resource: "@GvnSnippetryBundle/Resources/config/validation.xml" }
```

But that didn't work. I didn't found any information about this. It seems that it should be loaded automatically. But it isn't.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem. Why do you want to import this file? Isn't this file already imported by the DI Extension of the Bundle?

Comment: Well if that is.. I don't think the DI Extension is being loaded. How can I check this ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've researched this to the bottom. The validation.xml actually gets loaded but with the cache (even in developers mode) it isn't used.